# chrome redirects to secure assets

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, ssl

I experience a strange behavior with chrome. I have the WP site http://flytime.hu, it does not have SSL, never had. If I try to login to the site (/wp-login.php), it tries to load a lot of assets (css, scripts) with https protocol, however the the page itself is loaded with http.

If I check the page source I can see urls beginning with https. This does not occur in Firefox (or other browser). I cannot login, since the login redirects to https protocol as well (https:// flytime.hu/wp-login.php).

After a trial like this the main site behaves the same way (assets not loaded because SSL protocol error). Then I have to completely reinstall chrome to get the main site back at least. Clearing cookies, cache and all does not help.

Source in chrome (URL: http:// flytime.hu/):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bkb-font-awesome-styles-css'  href='https://flytime.hu/wp-content/plugins/bwl-kb-manager/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1.0.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bkbm-custom-styles-css'  href='https://flytime.hu/wp-content/plugins/bwl-kb-manager/css/bkbm-custom-styles.css?ver=1.0.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='https://flytime.hu/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='blogsynthesis_jss_css-css'  href='https://flytime.hu/wp-content/plugins/jquery-smooth-scroll/css/jss-style.min.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Source in Firefox (URL: http:// flytime.hu/):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bkb-font-awesome-styles-css'  href='http://flytime.hu/wp-content/plugins/bwl-kb-manager/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1.0.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bkbm-custom-styles-css'  href='http://flytime.hu/wp-content/plugins/bwl-kb-manager/css/bkbm-custom-styles.css?ver=1.0.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://flytime.hu/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='blogsynthesis_jss_css-css'  href='http://flytime.hu/wp-content/plugins/jquery-smooth-scroll/css/jss-style.min.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on function.php file for now.

```
function https_chromev44fix() {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = false;
}

add_action( 'init', 'https_chromev44fix', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Chrome in Version 44.0.2403.89 m in order with nginx does a https redirect instead of http like I configured in the nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Chrome to **Version 45.0.2454.12 dev-m** and the thing went away.